# How to configure Serilog's ContainsKey-Filter in a external JSON config file?

Tags: serilog

How can I configure the filter `lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(lc => lc.Properties.ContainsKey("log_gp")` in a external applicationsettings.json file? I tried

```
  "Filter": [
    {
      "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
      "Args": {
        "expression": "Contains(Properties, 'log_gp')"
      }
    }
  ]
```

but no success.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dotnet add package serilog.expressions
```

then:

```json
  "Using": ["Serilog.Expressions"],
  "Filter": [
    {
      "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
      "Args": {
        "expression": "IsDefined(log_gp)"
      }
    }
  ]
```